# No visible @interface for 'NSMutableArray' declares the selector 'addUtilityButtonWithColor:icon:'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using a project on GitHub called SWTableViewCell. However, I am consistently getting this error: `No visible @interface for 'NSMutableArray' declares the selector 'addUtilityButtonWithColor:icon:'`.

The affected code is in here:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *cellId = @"Cell";

    SWTableViewCell *cell = (SWTableViewCell *)[table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSMutableArray *leftUtilityButtons = [NSMutableArray new];
        NSMutableArray *rightUtilityButtons = [NSMutableArray new];

        [leftUtilityButtons addUtilityButtonWithColor:
         [UIColor colorWithRed:0.00 green:0.4 blue:225 alpha:1.0]
                                                 icon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"]];
        [leftUtilityButtons addUtilityButtonWithColor:
         [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.5 blue:225 alpha:1.0]
                                                 icon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"clock.png"]];
        [leftUtilityButtons addUtilityButtonWithColor:
         [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.6 blue:225 alpha:1.0]
                                                 icon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cross.png"]];
        [leftUtilityButtons addUtilityButtonWithColor:
         [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.7 blue:225 alpha:1.0]
                                                 icon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"list.png"]];


        [rightUtilityButtons addUtilityButtonWithColor:
         [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:0.231f blue:0.188 alpha:1.0f]
                                                 title:@"Delete"];

        cell = [[SWTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                      reuseIdentifier:cellId
                                  containingTableView:table // For row height and selection
                                   leftUtilityButtons:leftUtilityButtons
                                  rightUtilityButtons:rightUtilityButtons];
        cell.delegate = self;

        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Medium" size:18];
        cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Medium" size:13];
    }
    // Configure cell

    // Sets the text for the cell

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Testing"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is a test."];

    return cell;

}
```

Why is this not working? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should have some category on NSMutableArray which contain method: 'addUtilityButtonWithColor:icon:'.

Comment: According to the example on [GitHub](https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell), the method name is `sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor`.

Comment: You lost NSMutableArray+SWUtilityButtons category http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/swtableviewcell-expose-utility-buttons-with-an-easy-to-use-uitableviewcell-subclass/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at the docs for `SWTableViewCell`. The method is called:

```
sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:icon:
```

So you want:

```
    [leftUtilityButtons sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:
     [UIColor colorWithRed:0.00 green:0.4 blue:225 alpha:1.0]
                                             icon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"]];
```

Comment: Incidentally, this is sort of a gross way to do things, if you ask me.

Comment: @AndrewMadsen Agreed. Adding a category method to `NSMutableArray` just to make it ever so slightly easier to create a button is lame.

Comment: Fixed. It works now. And I agree with @AndrewMadsen: it's not the greatest way to do things.